# SVG styling not applying in illustrator

Tags: svg, styles, adobe-illustrator

I'm generating an SVG in a [web app](http://meepmoop.com/phylogram/demo.php) and allowing users to save it; the SVG embeds the styles in the header of the image.

When a user opens it in their browser (testing in Chrome) it style properly:
[image]

However in Illustrator it seems the styles aren't being applied:
[image]

What am I missing?  Download the actual SVG [here](http://meepmoop.com/phylogram/demo.svg).

Comment: please create a [mcve] with the emphasis on minimal here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is really with Illustrator's SVG importer.

You probably have to choose between two solutions:

1. Tell your users that saved SVGs won't work with some programs (like Illustrator)
2. Modify your graph generating code so that it doesn't rely on CSS classes.

   For example: change the elements that use

   ```
   class="link"
   ```

   To instead set the style properties explicitly:

   ```
   fill="none" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="2px"
   ```

Or maybe you can find a script on the net somewhere that does that for you.

Comment: As you suggested, I ended up setting the .link style inline - that gets me "close enough" on the Illustrator side.  Also, for those looking, the [following](https://github.com/lukehorvat/computed-style-to-inline-style/blob/master/test.js) script will inline all your CSS styles.